# How to make redirect go to alternate web page if Shift key is being held?

Tags: php, java, webserver, html

I am trying to make a secret alternate redirect on a web page that redirects to an alternate page when holding down the key, otherwise it redirects to the regular redirect page.

Example/Clarification:
So you have a regular redirect, it redirects to page1.html, but if the user is holding down Shift key while the redirect is being executed or activated then it redirects to page2.html instead - is this possible? If so what is the most basic simplest way to do this? I couldn't find anything on Google anywhere regarding what I am trying to do here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9375031/1737973 ?